# Using a script to send Delete key through TelNet connection

Tags: python

I am writing a script that reboots the computer and breaks into the bios using a Telnet connection.

I have found that, `TLNT.write(chr(3))` functions as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.  Which is simply a control code.

I am looking for a similar solution, except for the <kbd>DELETE</kbd> key.

Thank you for the help!

Here is where I got the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> control code:
http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm

Comment: The Delete key is also called the Backspace key, `chr(8)`.

Comment: Why do you think it will help you to get into BIOS through telnet?

Comment: in general, for control codes may vary depending on terminal, so answer shoul depend on your software and its settings on the receiving side. If you describe it more thoroughly you will probably get more helpful answer.